# Change the position of Tabs' indicator in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the position of the indicator to the top of TAB instead of the bottom like:

[image: here]

I checked and tried to update CSS but it didn't work. I'm new to react so I couldn't customize the components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create an example in codesandbox that I share with you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-p0y9t?file=/index.js

You can pass to Tabs the property classes to override internal classes.
In this case you can pass a new class to the indicator and override his style.
Take a look at the link below

https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the IDEA from your example and used the example
 in https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api. It solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks @Macro Moretti. It really helps me on solving my issue. I was working on vertical tabs. In this case, I have to override the indicator class and give 0px to its left instead of the top.

Answer (score 15):

To reinforce @Xavier 's answer, I found that we could use the `TabIndicatorProps` prop for `Tabs` component as below.

```
<Tabs
   TabIndicatorProps={{
      sx: {          
         top: 0
      }
    }}
  >
  <Tab label="One" />
  <Tab label="Two" />
  <Tab label="Three" />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 10):

## 2022 Solution

https://mui.com/styles/basics/

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

> ⚠️ @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

You can utilise the `sx` property on the component to access any css classes directly.

https://mui.com/api/tabs/#css

```
<Tabs
  orientation="vertical"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    '.MuiTabs-indicator': {
      left: 0,
    },
  }}
>
  <Tab label="One" />
  <Tab label="Two" />
  <Tab label="Three" />
</Tabs>
```